# Getting DirectX 7.0 to run on Windows 98 SE inside of a VMware Workstation Player (v14) VM

Tags: vmware-workstation, directx, windows-98

I'm trying to get DirectX 7.0 to be able to run on the Windows 98 SE that I installed from an OEM install CD-ROM disc. The Windows 98 SE actually came pre-installed with DirectX 6.0, but after installing The Sims in my virtual machine (for which I'm using VMware Workstation Player v. 14), I was prompted to install the more recent (at the time, obviously) DirectX 7 that Maxis, the game producer, included with The Sims. After doing so, and after installing VMware Tools, switching the display resolution to ~16m colours and 1024x768 display resolution, and then attempting to play the game using the installed 1024x768 executable, I get the following error:

[image: "Game cannot be started because: DirectX 7, or Service Pack 3 for NT4, is required. It could not be located."]

> Game cannot be started because:
>
> DirectX 7, or Service Pack 3 for NT4, is required. It could not be located.

Anyway, can someone provide me some instructions on next steps here?

Comment: Is DirectX 7.0 showing as installed in Add/Remove Programs? Look for a DirectX 7.0 installer in the game files and try installing it manually. Sometimes 3rd party installers run through a 1st party installer fail and the 1st party installer doesn't pass the errors through.

Comment: Thanks, but to answer your question, I wondered about that so I tried installing DirectX 7.0 from the "oldversion.com" website that I'd seen other users reference on other online computer software assistance forums. Same problem.

I'm not sure if this could be the problem or not, but apparently one needs to enable "hardware acceleration" on the "host computer" (which is my computer) in order to enable the corresponding option on the "guest OS" (virtual computer) in VMware Player? 1/2

Comment: However, I've tried installing the ATI Catalyst Software for Windows 8 (no version exists for Windows 10), which just plain doesn't load. If you can tell me if (a) this is the reason why DirectX isn't working and (b) how to enable hardware acceleration in Windows 10, it'd be appreciated. All of the online tutorials reference Windows screens that don't exist. So frustrating! 2/2

Comment: Try running DxDiag.exe and see what that says. It should be in `C:\Windows\System32`. It should be included with DirectX 6.0 and up.

Answer (score 1):

DirectX is not supported in VMWare for Windows 9.x rather starting from Win2k onwards.